# android cannot resolve method 'startsWith(java.lang.string)'

Tags: android

So I am creating an android application which opens any website entered by the user. I use the following code to achieve this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtbox_website);
    }

    public void open(View view){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

But when I include this code:

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

to check that the string starts with http or https or not, I get an error.
The error is this:

> cannot Resolve method `startsWith(java.lang.string)`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `startsWith()` is a `String s` method, you are using it in a `EditText`. To fix this issue, you have to get the text:

```
  String urlText = url.getText().toString();
     if (!urlText.startsWith("http://") && !urlText.startsWith("https://")) {
    urlText = "http://" + url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luiz Fernando Salvaterra. But now in the line url = "http://" + url; I get an error that: Incompatible types Required : android.widget.EditText Found: java.lang.String

Comment: Done:! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me

```
                   String linkUrl;
                    if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
                        linkUrl = url;
                    } else if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
                        linkUrl = url;
                    } else {
                        linkUrl = "http://" + url + "";
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linkUrl));
                    startActivity(i);
```